# Существует ли связь между словами "скалдырничать" и "калдырить"?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, корень-слова

На форуме разбирался вопрос о слове "скалдырничество"; существует слово "калдырь" — пьяница, а также образованный от него глагол "калдырить" — много пить. Интересно было бы послушать ваше мнение по поводу происхождения слова "калдырь". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это производное от холод, холодрыга - колдрыг-калдырь. 
Результат сильного похмелья, с бодуна после запоя колотун, трясет. Пьяница даже выговорить нормально не может.

Comment: Не знаю, кто тут плюсы ставил, долго ждал и надеялся, но впустую.

Словечки эти идут  от тех, кто за кордон ездил, там в барах  Cold Drink холодная выпивка: коктейль, виски со льдом и пр. объявления висят: cold drinks are sold here. в восьмидесятых прошлого века еще говорили: пойдем калдринкнем.

Comment: >Не знаю, кто тут плюсы ставил, долго ждал и надеялся, но впустую.

Ничего, админ в курсе.
Отминусил, кстати, я. За полное отсутствие всякого академического смысла. Ваша этимология, простите, ничего общего с научным подходом не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, происходит от "кэлдэра́ры" ("кэлдэра́ри") - этническая группа цыган, проживающих в России. Занимаются скупкой и перепродажей металлолома, гаданием на улицах, мелкой торговлей (нелегальный алкоголь и наркотики) и т. п. Отличаются низким уровнем образования. Помните бучу цыганского табора в посёлках Плеханово и Косая гора Тульской области? - Это они, кэлдэра́ры.

Answer (score 0):

Калтыр по татарски дрожать. Может отсюда?